# How to query based on the the date of a specific state change transition (EX: date of transition to 'Ready for Deploy')

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Our DevOps work item flow is New > Approved > Committed > In QA > Ready for Deploy > Done. A variant is any state can transition to "Removed".

I am creating a query that needs to show all work items where testing was not complete (not transitioned to "Ready for Deploy") by the end of the sprint, or were transitioned to "Removed" after the sprint was closed.

I cannot figure out how to query for the combination of a specific state transitions limited by date.

I am wondering at this point if A) I need to add custom date fields associated with each of the states I need to query on, B) I need to configure the states to one of the standard/out of the box date fields supported in DevOps, or C) Do some advanced/intimidating history query voodoo with skills I don't have yet. (I would prefer to stay in the WYSWYG query editor if it is feasible).

Thank you for any insight!

I have captured all items that have not transitioned to "Ready for Deploy" at the time the query is run, but

- I do not know how to capture items that were changed to "Ready for Deploy" after the last day of the sprint, and I do not know how to capture items removed after the end of the sprint.
- It seems the "State Change Date" field will pick up ANY state change, and not specifically the state changes I am interested in. This seems like handy generic field to see if there is activity on items, and not specific kinds of activity (specific state changes), which is what I need.
- I have looked at all the standard date fields and there appears to be no granular date associated with "Ready for Deploy" or "Removed" states specifically.